# Boostrap vertical sizing with different style width and height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set verticaly icon on profile photo card inside div to be in the middle in white box(div), but dont know why it doesnt works. When I use `style="width: 300px; height: 300px;` for div square I can center it on horizontaly, but not verticaly :/ Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Anyway is there any way how to resize bootstrap icons except display-1???

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  <div class="container-sm offset-md">
        <h1 class="p-4 m-4">Nastavení profilu</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Osobní údaje
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Jméno">
                    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Příjmení">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
                    <input type="date" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4 bg-light">
                    Profilová fotografie
                    <div class=" square text-center border display-1 m-3 bg-white mx-auto">
                        <i class="bi bi-person-fill align-middle justify-content-center text-secondary"></i>
                    </div>

                    <input type="file" id="customFile" name="file" hidden="">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" for="customFile">Nahrát</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Smazat</button>
                            
                            <p class="text-muted mt-3 mb-0">Poznámka: Minimální velikost 300px x 300px</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Změna hesla
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Zobrazit/skrýt podrobnosti
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because bootstrap sets `vertical-align` ,

just add `.bi::before, [class^="bi-"]::before, [class*=" bi-"]::before{ vertical-align:0 !important; }`

```css
.bi::before, [class^="bi-"]::before, [class*=" bi-"]::before{
vertical-align:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
  <div class="container-sm offset-md">
        <h1 class="p-4 m-4">Nastavení profilu</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Osobní údaje
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Jméno">
                    <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Příjmení">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
                    <input type="date" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4 bg-light">
                    Profilová fotografie
                    <div class=" square text-center border display-1 m-3 bg-white mx-auto">
                        <i class="bi bi-person-fill align-middle justify-content-center text-secondary"></i>
                    </div>

                    <input type="file" id="customFile" name="file" hidden="">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" for="customFile">Nahrát</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Smazat</button>
                            
                            <p class="text-muted mt-3 mb-0">Poznámka: Minimální velikost 300px x 300px</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Změna hesla
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card p-4 m-4">
                    Zobrazit/skrýt podrobnosti
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```